# Back to back steam and leaf plot

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

I'm having a bit of trouble finishing up my back to back stem and leaf plot. I know what a back to back stem and leaf plot is and I also know how to make one but here is my question: When doing a back to back stem and leaf plot the stem is always in order like for example 1,2,3,4,5 or 12,13,14,15,16 and so on. What if let's say my stem starts on 0 and ends on 5 so it would be 0,1,2,3,4,5 but 3 and 4 on the stem have no leaf to go with it or data for it, do I still keep the 3 and 4 on the stem or do I skip them and do it like this 0,1,2,5?

My work

Do I do it like this:

```
    5|0|4,6,9
  5,4|1|4,8
5,4,3|2|2,3,5
     |3|
     |4|
  9,8|5|1
```

or should I do it like this:

```
    5|0|4,6,9
  5,4|1|4,8
5,4,3|2|2,3,5
  9,8|5|1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skip, just like you have in the latter.

See http://www.basic-mathematics.com/stem-and-leaf-plot.html for more when the total scores are less than 100, and here http://www.purplemath.com/modules/stemleaf2.htm for when they're greater than 100.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
5&0&469\\
54&1&48\\
543&2&235\\
 98&5&1
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up for me!

Comment: I am not convinced skipping gaps is wise: it means that a glance (without reading the numbers) doe not show the distribution

Comment: @Henry, It seems to be a matter of convention. I do believe you are correct.  It can be a good idea to include the gaps, if you'd like to get a better idea of the distribution.

Comment: So do I include the gaps? (In this case 3 and 4)

Answer (score 1):

According the results based on two R libraries, aplpack and graphics, we can see that both keep the gaps visible. Moreover, according the book ...

> Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences 8th
>   Edition, Jay L. Devore

one of the aspects which Stem and Leaf diagrams describes, is the occurrence of gaps in the data.

Result generated by *aplpack*:

```
stem.leaf.backback(data1, data2, m = 1, trim.outliers = FALSE, depths = FALSE)

  5| 0 |469    
 54| 1 |48     
543| 2 |235    
   | 3 |       
   | 4 |       
 98| 5 |1      
   | 6 |       
___________________
n:    8     9
```